# Generating key derivation in construct_miner_tx

Tags: transaction-data, elliptic-curve, transaction-key

Good day!

I am trying to understand the `construct_miner_tx` function inside `cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp` and I am stuck on comparing what is being discussed in the *zero to monero* reference pdf regarding multiple outputs. Where it generally states (based on what I understand), tx pubkeys are generated in `derive_public_keys` in `crypto.cpp`, where one of its parameters is the **key derivation**. So based on the code, **key derivation** is called in `construct_miner_tx` in:

```
bool r = crypto::generate_key_derivation(miner_address.m_view_public_key, txkey.sec, derivation);
```

In the paper it states that the `PvK` and `tx sk` are multiplied by a cofactor of 8 to ensure that the output point is within `G` subgroup.

So key derivation is `8*(PvK txsk)`, right?

Then `derive_public_key` is `H(8*(PvK txsk) || output_i)G + PsK`?

```
PsK = Public spend key
txsk = transaction secret key
PvK = Public view key
```

Do all my assumptions make sense? And is the output of `generate_key_derivation` a plain public key? And is the shared secret key the output of `hash_to_scalar`?

Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by first defining a couple of things. *Outputs* created in a coinbase transaction can later be spent by using them as *inputs* to a subsequent transaction. A transaction also has a *public key*, which is used as the *public* part of a secret (it's shared, it's in the tx which is on the blockchain).

When constructing a coinbase (miner) transaction, the generated coins are placed as outputs of the transaction. These outputs are only spendable by the miner - they are constructed in such a way that only the miner can spend them (you would need the miners private spend key).

So, in `construct_miner_tx`:

```
crypto::generate_key_derivation(miner_address.m_view_public_key, txkey.sec, derivation);
```

Where `miner_address.m_view_public_key` is `A` (the miners public view key) and `txkey.sec` is `r` (the tx private key), the output of the function `generate_key_derivation` (which is placed in `derivation`), is **`8rA`**.

> So key derivation is 8*(PvK txsk), right?

Correct.

Then:

```
crypto::derive_public_key(derivation, no, miner_address.m_spend_public_key, out_eph_public_key);
```

This is placing `H(8rA||i)G + B` in `out_eph_public_key`. This is an output key that becomes spendable by the miner. There can be more than one output key (hence this is in a loop and is indexed by `i` in `H(8rA||i)G + B`).

> Then derive_public_key is H(8*(PvK txsk) || output_i)G + PsK?

Thus, correct.

> Do all my assumptions make sense? And is the output of generate_key_derivation a plain public key?

Not quite. `generate_key_derivation` is creating `8rA` (a point), which is then used by `derive_public_key` to create an output key (or in Monero parlance, a stealth address).

> And is the shared secret key the output of hash_to_scalar?

No. `hash_to_scalar` just takes a hash and converts it to a scalar. The public part of the shared secret is the tx public key, created earlier in `construct_miner_tx`:

```
keypair txkey = keypair::generate(hw::get_device("default"));
```

This is creating `r` and `R` (in txkey). The shared part is `R` which is included in the tx as the tx public key (stuffed into the tx field `tx_extra`, `add_tx_pub_key_to_extra`). Only someone with `r` or `a` can derive the shared secret `aR` or `rA` (as used in the calculations above). The recipient uses `aR` in their side of the calculations when scanning transactions, to know the transaction is destined for them. `r` is not stored in the transaction, it is used for the sender-side of the shared secret (`rA` above).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @jtgrassie! Just wanted to clarify, I understand output_index is concatenated into the hash to have the transaction output key uniqueness, what happens if every coinbase transaction has the same transaction output key? Will that be a valid miner transaction? will the reward be given? how is this handled?

Comment: output_index is the output index *within* that transaction. It's parameter `no` in the loop (that is `i` in `H(8rA||i)G + B`). Therefore it's always unique within that tx. And thus every output key is globally unique (`r` is unique to the tx and `i` to the output).

Comment: thank you! I was just curious on the part where output_index _i_ is not in play, meaning, there is not such uniqueness(f.e in bitcoin outputs having same address). So is it safe to say that, if an output is not unique, that won't be considered a valid output? thus, not a valid tx?

Comment: Every output is unique because of `r` and `i`. If a duplicate output key was created (manually for example), the tx would get rejected.

Comment: Thank you again! This totally makes sense. Since I tried to change the `derive_public_key()` to use the `G` or the base_point. So right now, my transactions have same output key every a coinbase transaction is mined, at first rewards are given to the miner_address since, that is the first mined block, thus making the first output key as unique, but the 2nd to the n - 1 coinbase tx, all were rejected and I did not get the rewards. Thanks.

Sample output of my experiment, when I do `show_transfers` https://pastebin.com/WxWvVEEZ